# OpenAPI /api-docs returns result to parse as JWT string instead of JSON

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have spring boot application, 2.7.14. I added OpenAPI in it and but problem is that i can get endpoints. When swagger or me send request to /api-docs enpoint it returns JWT parsed string not JSON. I dont have any filter or anything but also i couldn't find solution to it.

Comment: share you OpenAPI description and your code

Comment: its standart description. I added maven libraries and add this configuration class `@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig  {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info()
                        .title("My API")
                        .version("1.0")
                        .description("My Custom API for demonstration"));
    }
}`